# Nothing was returned from render Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I started looking at next.js technology, how can I solve this error, please can you help me ? what is the source of the problem ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYKki.jpg)

```
import React from 'react'

import Button from "../components/button"

function HomePage() {
    return;
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Next.js!</h1>
      <Button> Merhaba </Button>
    </div>
    }
  
  export default HomePage
```

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './button.module.css'

function Button ({children}) {
return <button type="button" className = {styles.button}>{children}</button> 
}


export default Button
```

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo. You need to `return` the `<div>`, but you put it on a new line and with a semicolon before it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `HomePage` functional component, you should be returning a component, but your return statement is followed by a semicolon, which terminates that line so you end up returning nothing.

If you want your component to be on a different line from the `return` expression, you can wrap your component in parentheses, like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome to Next.js!</h1>
        <Button> Merhaba </Button>
    </div>
)
```

Do note though, that if you don't need the `<div>` tags there for styling or something else, it is considered a better practice to use a [React Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to wrap your components.

```
return (
    <>
        <h1>Welcome to Next.js!</h1>
        <Button> Merhaba </Button>
    </>
)
```